# iOS: Loading UIViewController with a popover segue, trying to dismiss itself

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UIViewController` instance segued to by way of a popover segue. It is NOT a `UIPopOverViewCOntroller` so there's no `dismissPopoverAnimated:` method.

I have a button in the its main `UIView` that I want to dismiss the VC. How can this be done?

I have this, which does not work:

```
- (IBAction)submitButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the correct code usually if you aren't going to do anything in the completion handler just set it to nil.  Did you create this button in the storyboard and if so did you link it to this action?

If you set a breakpoint on that line of code does it actually run when you click the button?  If not then your button isn't linked to the IBAction.